# How to share code between projects of different types in visual studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I know there is someone who has post some questions like this. But my problem is a little different.

My program has two versions, one is for PC and the other one is for Windows Phone. In my case, they both use a same algorithm. I want to share the codes between two projects.

First, I tried to create a project containing these codes, then add them to my projects as a reference. But here is the problem, if i create a Windows Form Application project, I can't reference it in a WP project, and vice versa.

Second, I tried to add these codes to my projects as a link. But I have lots of files to share, I don't want add them one by one. And these shared files will mass my project directory.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a "[Portable class Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/gg597391%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)" project and put your common code in there. it will create a dll. Reference it in other projects and it will work fine.

> Using the Portable Class Library project, you can build portable
>   assemblies that work without modification on the .NET Framework,
>   Silverlight, Windows Phone 7, or Xbox 360 platforms. Without the
>   Portable Class Library project, you must target a single platform and
>   then manually rework the class library for other platforms. The
>   Portable Class Library project supports a subset of assemblies from
>   these platforms, and provides a Visual Studio template that makes it
>   possible to build assemblies that run without modification on these
>   platforms. - MSDN

Answer (score 1):

sounds to me like you need to make a Class Library project.  Create that and you can put in whatever code you want, then compile it to a dll, and reference it in any of your other projects.

Comment: In Visual Studio, a Class Library project still has to choose project type. Such as Windows Phone Class Library, Windows Class Library. And projects of different types can't reference each other.